# Opening market from ionic fails

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have this ionic app where I put code to open the browser and go to app store or google play, depending on OS.
The call to App Store works. The string for app store is:

```
market = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my_app_name/id12345';
```

while for android is:

```
market = 'market://details?id=<package_name>';
```

The code to open the browser is:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(market, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

When I try to open in android, some kind of browser opens and displays the message:

```
"Web page not available. The webpage at market://details?id=my_app_id might be temporarly down ..."
```

Before this, the string for google play was the one you normally use in a browser, which is:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

In that case the message was about the broser not supporting the call to google play. It asked if I wanted to download google play app.

I guess the right way is to use the "market"-prefix? But still dont understand why its not showing the app.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I looked into 'cordova-plugin-market' source code for ios. This is how the url to appstore is built:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/%@", appId];
```

And this is how url looks if you want to navigate from PC browser:

https://itunes.apple.com/app/**id**333903271  (twitter for example)

So if you use this plugin for Ios, consider adding 'id' prefix, and instead of using bundle Id (package name) use Apple ID of your app. For android of course com.example.package will be enough

```
let appId;

if (this.platform.is("android")) {
  appId = "com.example.package"
} else {
  appId =  "id1234567"
}

this.market.open(appId).then(response => {
  console.debug(response);

}).catch(error => {
  console.warn(error);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I added
cordova plugin add https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market
And then it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the other way around. The play store works fine but the app store is not working. Did you use `this.market.open('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my_app_name/id12345')` for iOS?. I'm currently using the plugin like this: `this.market.open(package_name)` and it works only for android.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { InAppBrowserOptions, InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { Market } from "@ionic-native/market";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";

constructor(private market:Market, private inappBrowswer:InAppBrowser, 
private platform:Platform)
{
this.onUpdateNow();//Call the update function
}

onUpdateNow() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is("ios")) {
        //replace '310633997' with your iOS App ID
        this.openInAppStore('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/310633997'); //call the openInAppStore
      } else if (this.platform.is("android")) {
        //replace 'com.whatsapp.saint' with your Android App ID
        this.market.open("com.whatsapp.saint").then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
  });
}

openInAppStore(link) {
    let options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      location: 'yes',//Or 'no' 
    };
    let target = "_blank";
    this.inappBrowswer.create(link, target, options);
  }
```

Comment: You should add a description with your code. Answers with just code are frowned upon :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the plugin with capacitor and its working like a charm using the package name and the app id (for android and ios accordingly):

```
  public goToStore() {
    const appId = 1234512345;
    const packageName = 'com.test.app';
    Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android' ? this.market.open(packageName) : this.market.open(appId);
  }
```

The plugins:

```
"@ionic-native/market": "5.36.0",
"cordova-plugin-market": "1.2.0",
```